# Listview not behaving well with Folding Cell Library

Tags: java, android

I have a problem using folding cell library from the RAMOTION
I have implemented everything but I am facing a problem with the list view

I have a list of planets and when user tap on let's say Jupiter the view gets unfolded and more information is visible to the user and when user tap on the same view which is  seeing then the view gets folded

**Problem**

if the user scrolls down the list and then scroll back up and come back up to Jupiter the view remains unfolded and it is happening to all the view.

I appreciate if anyone helps me out

folding state 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pNkD.png)
unfolding state
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvR63.png)

**AdapterClass**

```
@SuppressWarnings({"WeakerAccess", "unused"})
public class SolarSystemFoldingCellListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SolarSystemItemFoldingCell> {

    private HashSet<Integer> unfoldedIndexes = new HashSet<>();
    private View.OnClickListener defaultRequestBtnClickListener;

    private int incomingPosition ;
    public SolarSystemFoldingCellListAdapter(Context context, List<SolarSystemItemFoldingCell> objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        // get item for selected view
        SolarSystemItemFoldingCell solarSystemItemFoldingCell = getItem(position);
        // if cell is exists - reuse it, if not - create the new one from resource
        FoldingCell cell = (FoldingCell) convertView;
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (cell == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            cell = (FoldingCell) vi.inflate(R.layout.solar_system_folding_cell, parent, false);
            // binding view parts to view holder



            viewHolder.foldingCell = cell.findViewById(R.id.folding_cell);

            viewHolder.relativeLayoutFolded = cell.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutFolded);
            viewHolder.linearLayoutFolded = cell.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutFolded);
            viewHolder.planetOrStarNameFolded = cell.findViewById(R.id.planetOrStarNameFolded);
            viewHolder.mass = cell.findViewById(R.id.mass);
            viewHolder.actualMass = cell.findViewById(R.id.actualMass);
            viewHolder.distance = cell.findViewById(R.id.distance);
            viewHolder.actualDistance = cell.findViewById(R.id.actualDistance);
            viewHolder.diameter = cell.findViewById(R.id.diameter);
            viewHolder.actualDiameter = cell.findViewById(R.id.actualDiameter);
            viewHolder.speed = cell.findViewById(R.id.speed);
            viewHolder.actualSpeed = cell.findViewById(R.id.actualSpeed);
            viewHolder.moreInfoButton = cell.findViewById(R.id.button);
            viewHolder.frameLayoutUnfolded = cell.findViewById(R.id.frameLayoutUnfolded);
            viewHolder.planetOrStarNameUnfolded = cell.findViewById(R.id.planetOrStarNameUnfolded);

            cell.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            // for existing cell set valid valid state(without animation)
            if (unfoldedIndexes.contains(position)) {
                cell.unfold(true);
            } else {
                cell.fold(true);
            }
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) cell.getTag();
        }

        if (null == solarSystemItemFoldingCell)
            return cell;

        // bind data from selected element to view through view holder
        viewHolder.planetOrStarNameFolded.setText(solarSystemItemFoldingCell.getPlantOrStarNameFolded());
        viewHolder.actualMass.setText(solarSystemItemFoldingCell.getActualMass());
        viewHolder.actualDistance.setText(solarSystemItemFoldingCell.getActualDistance());
        viewHolder.actualDiameter.setText(solarSystemItemFoldingCell.getActualDiameter());
        viewHolder.actualSpeed.setText(solarSystemItemFoldingCell.getActualSpeed());
        viewHolder.planetOrStarNameUnfolded.setText(String.valueOf(solarSystemItemFoldingCell.getPlanetOrStarNameUnfolded()));

        //setting Fonts

        viewHolder.planetOrStarNameFolded.setTypeface(App.getAppInstance().getArvoBold());

        viewHolder.mass.setTypeface(App.getAppInstance().getArvoBold());
        viewHolder.distance.setTypeface(App.getAppInstance().getArvoBold());
        viewHolder.diameter.setTypeface(App.getAppInstance().getArvoBold());
        viewHolder.speed.setTypeface(App.getAppInstance().getArvoBold());
        viewHolder.actualMass.setTypeface(App.getAppInstance().getArvoRegular());
        viewHolder.actualDistance.setTypeface(App.getAppInstance().getArvoRegular());
        viewHolder.actualDiameter.setTypeface(App.getAppInstance().getArvoRegular());
        viewHolder.actualSpeed.setTypeface(App.getAppInstance().getArvoRegular());

        viewHolder.moreInfoButton.setTypeface(App.getAppInstance().getArvoRegular());


        // set custom btn handler for list item from that item
        if (solarSystemItemFoldingCell.getRequestBtnClickListener() != null) {
            viewHolder.moreInfoButton.setOnClickListener(solarSystemItemFoldingCell.getRequestBtnClickListener());
        } else {
            // (optionally) add "default" handler if no handler found in item
            viewHolder.moreInfoButton.setOnClickListener(defaultRequestBtnClickListener);
        }

        viewHolder.relativeLayoutFolded.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Something gets clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                viewHolder.foldingCell.fold(false);
                registerFold(incomingPosition);

            }
        });


        return cell;
    }

    // simple methods for register cell state changes
    public void registerToggle(int position) {
        if (unfoldedIndexes.contains(position)) {
            registerFold(position);
            incomingPosition = position;
        }else
            registerUnfold(position);
    }

    public void registerFold(int position) {
        unfoldedIndexes.remove(position);
    }

    public void registerUnfold(int position) {
        unfoldedIndexes.add(position);
    }

    public View.OnClickListener getDefaultRequestBtnClickListener() {
        return defaultRequestBtnClickListener;
    }

    public void setDefaultRequestBtnClickListener(View.OnClickListener defaultRequestBtnClickListener) {
        this.defaultRequestBtnClickListener = defaultRequestBtnClickListener;
    }

    // View lookup cache
    private static class ViewHolder {

        RelativeLayout relativeLayoutFolded ;
        LinearLayout linearLayoutFolded ;

        TextView planetOrStarNameFolded;
        TextView mass;
        TextView actualMass;
        TextView distance;
        TextView actualDistance;
        TextView diameter;
        TextView actualDiameter;
        TextView speed;
        TextView actualSpeed ;
        Button moreInfoButton ;

        FrameLayout frameLayoutUnfolded ;
        TextView planetOrStarNameUnfolded;

        FoldingCell foldingCell ;
    }
}
```

**SolarSystemClass**

```
 private void listViewIntegration (){

        arrayList = addingDataIntoList();

        solarSystemFoldingCellListAdapter = new SolarSystemFoldingCellListAdapter(SolarSystem.this , arrayList);


        listView.setAdapter(solarSystemFoldingCellListAdapter);


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                int duration = 500;  //miliseconds
                int offset = 0;      //fromListTop

                 listView.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(position,offset,duration);

                // toggle clicked cell state
                ((FoldingCell) view).toggle(false);

                // register in adapter that state for selected cell is toggled

                solarSystemFoldingCellListAdapter.registerToggle(position);
               // listView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);


            }
        });



    }
```